# C# DataTable returns blank rows

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, datatable

Hello I am taking data from a one datatable that is coming from a session variable and trying to dump some of the data into new datatable however the new datatable returns empty?  Empty meaning that there are rows present in the new table. ie., my gridview returns several blank rows??  Not sure what is happening to the string variables?

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        if (Session["MyData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["MyData"];

            DataTable newdt = new DataTable();

            newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("studentName"));
            newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("inter"));
            newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CO"));
            newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("teacher"));
            newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date"));
            newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("desc"));
            DataRow newdr;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                name = row["NM"].ToString();
                term = row["term"].ToString();
                Mark = row["Mark"].ToString();
                period = row["period"].ToString();
                CN = row["CN"].ToString();
                CO = row["CO"].ToString();
                PID = row["PID"].ToString();
                //ADD TO NEW TABLE
                newdr = newdt.NewRow();
                name = newdr["studentName"].ToString();
                dlInter.SelectedText = newdr["inter"].ToString();
                CO = newdr["CO"].ToString();
                teacher = newdr["teacher"].ToString();
                date = newdr["date"].ToString();
                LabelDescript.Text = newdr["desc"].ToString();
                newdt.Rows.Add();
            }

            Repeater1.DataSource = newdt;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            GridView1.DataSource = newdt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
newdt.Rows.Add();
```

This will add an EMPTY row because the call to Add() without a DataRow or an object array is interpreted as adding a row without any value.
The solution is simple

```
newdt.Rows.Add(newdr);
```

Also the code before the Add is wrong because you are inverting the variables around the equal sign

```
newdr["studentName"] = name;
newdr["inter"] = dlInter.SelectedText;
newdr["CO"] = CO;
newdr["teacher"] = teacher
newdr["date"] = date;
newdr["desc"] = LabelDescript.Text;
```